# Run different rails apps on same domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to run a separate Rails app on the same domain? Specifically I am on Heroku and would like to namespace two apps.

MySite.com to run on Rails app 1.
MySite.com/different/2 triggers Rails app 2.

Comment: I have done this by using a reverse proxy like Nginx. All requests goes to Nginx and nginx routes to appropriate apps. I have never done this in heroku. See if they have a load balancer / reverse proxy option

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Phusion Passenger. I have no idea if this is possible through Heroku, but I have set it up for AWS with only a little pain.

There is a Passenger mod for Apache that enables this.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible on heroku.